# How to move multiple select options up/down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a custom dropdown field editor and would like to add the ability to move the selected options up or down, and remove them as well. I have this mostly implemented, but for some reason it keeps moving the options up twice, instead of once and won't move the options down. Removing works as expected.

I reviewed the following jQuery documentation but can't seem to get this working. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

- https://api.jquery.com/prev/
- https://api.jquery.com/before/
- https://api.jquery.com/next/
- https://api.jquery.com/after/

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPq04.png)

```
div[class="my-4"]
    div[class="flex items-center"]
        select[name="event_form_field_dropdown_options" id="dropdown-options" required="required" class="w-full" multiple="multiple"]
    div[class="ml-2 flex flex-col gap-2"]
        button[type="button" class="" id="move-dropdown-options-up" title="Move Up"]
        svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-primary-blue-dark hover:text-primary-blue"
             path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 20.25a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75V6.31l-5.47 5.47a.75.75 0 01-1.06-1.06l6.75-6.75a.75.75 0 011.06 0l6.75 6.75a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-5.47-5.47V19.5a.75.75 0 01-.75.75z" clip-rule="evenodd"
        button[type="button" class="" id="move-dropdown-options-down" title="Move Down"]
            svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-primary-blue-dark hover:text-primary-blue"
                path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2.25a.75.75 0 01.75.75v16.19l6.22-6.22a.75.75 0 111.06 1.06l-7.5 7.5a.75.75 0 01-1.06 0l-7.5-7.5a.75.75 0 111.06-1.06l6.22 6.22V3a.75.75 0 01.75-.75z" clip-rule="evenodd"
        button[type="button" class="" id="remove-dropdown-options" title="Remove"]
            svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-red-600 hover:text-red-800"
                path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zm3 10.5a.75.75 0 000-1.5H9a.75.75 0 000 1.5h6z" clip-rule="evenodd"
```

```
    // Add a new dropdown option
      var option = $('#new-dropdown-option').val();
      if (option != '') {
        $('#dropdown-options').append('<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>');
        $('#new-dropdown-option').val('');
        $('#new-dropdown-option').focus();
      }
    });

    // Move the selected dropdown options up or down
    $('#move-dropdown-options-up').click(function() {
      $('#dropdown-options option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($("#dropdown-options option:selected").length > 1) {
          return; // don't allow moving multiple options at once
        }
        var option = $(this);
        console.log('selected', option.val());
        if(option.is(':first-child')) {
          console.log('next', $('#dropdown-options option:last-child').next().val());
          option.insertAfter($('#dropdown-options option:last-child').next());
        }
        else {
          console.log('prev', option.prev().val());
          option.insertBefore(option.prev());
        }
      });
    });
    $('#move-dropdown-options-down').click(function() {
      $('#dropdown-options option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($("#dropdown-options option:selected").length > 1) {
          return; // don't allow moving multiple options at once
        }
        var option = $(this);
        console.log('selected', option.val());
        if(option.is(':last-child')) {
          console.log('prev', $('#dropdown-options option:first-child').prev().val());
          option.insertBefore($('#dropdown-options option:first-child').prev());
        }
        else {
          console.log('next', option.next().val());
          option.insertAfter(option.next());
        }
      });
    });

    // Remove the selected dropdown options
    $('#remove-dropdown-options').click(function() {
      $('#dropdown-options option:selected').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
```

I am expecting the up/down actions to move the selected options up by 1 or down by 1 respectively. The Remove action works as expected.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/codelogix/pen/gOdmXbR

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added a CodePen to the post -> https://codepen.io/codelogix/pen/gOdmXbR
Interestingly it works on CodePen, but for some reason, I'm getting two events fired when I try this locally vs in the CodePren, which is why it's jumping two items instead of one, but I'm not sure why.